# PHPUnit processIsolation weirdness with constants - constant already defined

Tags: symfony, phpunit

We newly activated in our app/phpunit.xml.dist file of our Symfony 2 project the setting

```
processIsolation="true"
```

to minimize irritating dependencies between our single tests.

This runs well with the local installations of my colleagues (php 5.6.20 and php 5.6.22) but causes an endless list of errors with my setup (php 5.6.24) we all use Linux and the same phpunit version 4.8.6

The error I get is

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: PHP Notice:  Constant MB_CASE_UPPER already defined in
```

Annoyingly this error is thrown by a vendor package we included.

/vendor/symfony/polyfill-mbstring

If this article is still applying this is caused by the bootstrap file being called several times, which looks like I want to define the constant multiple times.
Source:
https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/phpunit/issues/314

I am quite lost how to fix this and would be glad of any hints, what is causing it and how to solve it.

I already experimented with several other settings in the xml file, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

So I got this solved although I don't know why.

So my system is running Ubuntu 15.04 and I have installed ondrejs php repository to be able to select the fitting php version for my project instead of being dependent on Ubuntu's sometimes antique versions.

So since my colleagues use php 5.6.20 and 5.6.22 I checked my version in the synaptic package manager and discovered that I somehow have two version of php installed at the same time. Weird. php5.6.23 (5.6.23+dfsg-1+deprecated+dontuse+deb.sury.org~wily+1) and simultaneously also version 5.6.24, which was used on the console.

So I am not sure if the version 24 caused the error or if the error was caused by having two versions, but by removing the version 24 now my tests are running again.